# Meromorphic function with non-negative real-part is in fact analytic/holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, singularity, meromorphic-functions

> Let $f$ be a meromorphic function on an open set $\Omega$ satisfying $Re~f \ge 0$. Prove that $f$ is in fact holomorphic.

I'm not entirely sure how to solve this, but here are some thoughts. Let $z_0$ be an isolated singularity of $f$, which, I suppose, we want to argue is in fact removable. Then $z_0$ with also be an isolated singularity of $h(z) := e^{-f(z)}$, because $z \mapsto e^{-z}$ is an entire function. But it's not hard to show that $|h(z)| \le 1$, so $h$ is bounded near $z_0$, which by Riemann's theorem means that $z_0$ is a removable singularity...But I'm not sure where to go from here...If $z \mapsto e^{-z}$ were invertible, then we'd be done, since it we could compose it with the analytic function $h$ to get back $f$, thereby proving $f$ analytic...

Comment: What has the title to do with the question?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Whoops. It has absolutely nothing to do with it. That was a question I was going to ask at one point. I'll fix it!

Comment: If $g(z)=e^{-f(z)}$ has a zero at $z_0$ then $f(z)=-\log g(z)$ has a logarithmic branch point, not meromorphic. Anyway if $f\ne 0$ is meromorphic at $z_0$ then $f(z)=C (z-z_0)^n +O((z-z_0)^{n+1})$ for some $n$ and $C\ne 0$ and $\Re f(z)) \ge 0$ implies $n=0$.

Comment: Many details omitted: If $1/f$ has a zero, by the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)), the image of $1/f$ contains an open neighborhood of $0$...

Comment: Yet another way: If $\psi$ maps the right half plane onto the unit disk conformally (think Cayley transform), then $\psi\circ f$ is bounded.

Comment: @Jose27 By right half-plane, do you mean $\{z \in \Bbb{C} : Re (z) \ge 0 \}$ or $\{z \in \Bbb{C} : Re (z) > 0 \}$. $f$ maps $\Omega$ to $\{z \in \Bbb{C} : Re (z) \ge 0 \}$, which is a problem, because the Cayley transform $z \mapsto \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ doesn't map it to the unit disc....unless I made a mistake somewhere, or perhaps you have a different Cayley transform in mind.

Comment: @EricTowers I omitted many details or reuns did? I certainly left out many details. Btw, are you suggesting an alternate proof? You're using the fact that $f$ has a pole at $z=z_0$ if and only if $1/f$ has a root at $z=z_0$?

Comment: The colon implies the two independent clauses are related.  My one-line hint (naturally) omits many details.  And, I am suggesting a different proof method.  (One good (?) property of complex analysis is that there are usually several ways to arrive at a result.)

Comment: The Cayley transform maps $\{ z: Re(z)\geq 0\}$ into $\{ w: |w|\leq 1\}$ (it omits one point on the boundary of the disk, which corresponds to the point at infinity). This is good enough for what you want. Another way is to note that $f(\Omega)$ is open (by the open mapping theorem), and so the image is actually contained in $\{ z: Re(z)>0\}$.

Comment: @EricTowers Ah, I think I got it. If $f$ has a pole at $z=z_0$ then $1/f$ has a root at $z=z_0$. Since $\Omega$ is open, $B(z_0,r) \subseteq \Omega$ for some $r > 0$. Since $f$ is non-constant (otherwise things would be trivial), the image $(1/f)(B(z_0,r))$ is an open nbhd of $0$. In it, we can find $w$ with $Re(w)< 0$, and since it's in the image, there is some $z \in B(z_0,r)$ with $1/f(z)=w$ or $f(z) = 1/w$, but $Re(1/w) = Re(w)/|w|^2 < 0$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $f$ cannot have a pole...Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @user193319 : Sounds about right.